RavenDB: change IP address of *.ravendb.community
I'm running a Community version of RavenDB with mydb.ravendb.community domain name.
Today, IP address of my VM has changed and now I'm stuck. mydb.ravendb.community points to the old IP address and so, my clients do not work.
If I change the DNS locally (via /etc/hosts) and point the mydb.ravendb.community to new IP address, everything works ok.
But how could I update the mydb.ravendb.community, so it works globally?
I changed the ExternalIp setting of settings.json and restarted, but seems like this is not enough.

IP addresses could be changed via https://customers.ravendb.net
